# Discounting value by frequency

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Let's say there are two stocks `P` and `Q`.

stock `P` has a value of `1` and stock `Q` has a value of `2`.

There are `1.000.000` people in the population and they all choose between stocks `P` and `Q`.

I would like to discount the value of the stocks based on the number of people choosing the stock.

More specifically, the higher the number of people choosing the stock the smaller should its value be.

Can you recommend a good formula that discounts the values in the desired way?

To given an example:

on day 1:  `400.000` people are choosing `P` and `600.000 Q`. and the values of `P=1` and `Q=2`

on day 2:  `450.000` people are choosing `P` and `550.000 Q`. the values should be discounted such that

the value of `P` decreases and `Q` increases proportional to the number of people choosing the options.

Comment: What quantitative theory relates increased demand to reduced value? Without such a theory, this question seems impossible to answer objectively. Please tell us what this theory is.

Comment: I do not know such a theory, but the result I would like to get is very flexible. The only thing I would like to have is a function that increases or decreases a value proportional to how many people are using it. the amount of increase/decrease is irrelevant. any function that fitst this description is fine for my purpose

Comment: That leaves us wondering what a "good" function would be.  For instance, the function that discounts all values to zero has the properties you desire.  It sounds like you might have a specific quantitative meaning in mind where you write "proportional": could you clarify that?

Comment: you're point is well taken, but I really don't have anything specific in mind. It's even fine if the function produces negative values the only thing that matters is that it should either be increasing or decreasing relative to the number of people using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula lacks a theoretical basis but meets the criteria:
P_x=price of X
A,B= Number of buyers for good a or b.

P_a*B/(A+B) would be a good weight for A, suggesting the higher A is the lower the value is for A.

At the same time, P_b*A/(A+B) would be a good weight for B, suggesting the higher B is the lower the value is for B.

You also get the nice feature that (A+B)/(A+B) is 1, which might help make any math you're doing later nicer.